# how to generate an array of diffrent integers

Tags: c

i have been trying to make an array of complitely diffrent random integers, 25 of them between 1-75. have been getting stuck in an infinite loop. help greatly appreciated!

ive tried to look up solutions but i either didnt understand them or just didnt find anything that suits my level.
btw i have made sure that i used srand(time(NULL));

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        while (k != 1)
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % 75 + 1;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        k = 0;
    }
```

whole code:

```
/*********************************
* Class: MAGSHIMIM C2            *
* Week:                          *
* Name:                          *
* Credits:                       *
**********************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int arr[25] = { 0 };
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        while (k != 1)
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % 75 + 1;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        k = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

expecetd: a nice diffrent array but i got an infinite loop.

Comment: `while (k != 1) { ...; k++; ...;}` if you enter this loop, you'll leave it only when `k`, after having been _incremented_ (potentially multiple times), becomes equal to 1. Is `k` less than 1 at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: Add you whole code here. What is the initial vakue of variable **k**?

Comment: @ForceBru its default value is 0, that we will leave only if we found it once

Comment: you can replace your _while_ by a _do while_ also moving the reset of k at the beginning of the _do while_, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to make a pool or bag of numbers in the required range and pick from them. It is not much harder than repeated checking to see if the number has already been picked, and more efficient. Your modified program is now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRLEN  25          // how many to pick
#define NUMBERS 75          // range of available numbers
#if NUMBERS < ARRLEN        // precaution
    #error Impossible job!
#endif

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
// optional, for qsort
{
    return *(int *)a - *(int *)b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[ARRLEN];                    // final array
    int bag[NUMBERS];                   // bag of available numbers
    int avail = NUMBERS;                // size of bag available
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    // prepare the bag of available numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBERS; i++) {
        bag[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // fill the array with values from the bag
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRLEN; i++) {
        int index = rand() % avail;     // random index into array
        arr[i] = bag[index];            // take that number

        avail--;
        bag[index] = bag[avail];        // replace with the one from the top
    }

    // just to check, sort the array, can be deleted
    qsort(arr, ARRLEN, sizeof arr[0], cmp);

    // output the result
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRLEN; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I sorted the array to make it easy to see if there are duplicates. That `qsort` line and the `cmp` function can be deleted.

Program output from three runs

```
6 7 8 9 12 16 17 19 21 27 31 35 43 46 47 50 51 53 59 64 65 66 70 71 72
2 6 7 14 17 23 24 25 30 31 32 34 36 37 45 58 59 61 65 68 69 71 73 74 75
5 10 13 18 20 21 25 30 34 36 39 40 41 43 49 50 54 58 60 63 64 66 67 72 75
```

Comment: if the OP want 25 values between 1 and 123456789 it is a 'little' expensive way no ? ;-)

Comment: @bruno yes, but it is appropriate for this task, and many similar ones, such as drawing playing cards. But for your range is still do-able with a dynamic array which can then be `free`d.

Comment: depending on the complexity of _rand_, I confess I never looked at its implementation

Comment: @bruno I would build a random number from multiple calls and shifting - but you are taking this out of its proportion.

Comment: I got the liberty to edit my answer to compare your solution and mine, hope it is not a problem

Comment: @bruno this technique is a well-known method called the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and appears in many Stackoverflow questions & answers. It's an essential way to work when making card games and other situations where repetition is not allowed. Consider when there are very few free options left: a random fumble might *never* find a value for the last element ;(

Comment: The eternal fight between needed CPU time and needed memory size

Answer (score 0):

> ... but i got an infinite loop.

just replace

```
    while (k != 1)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 75 + 1;
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
          ...
        }
    }
    k = 0;
```

by

```
do
{
  k = 0;
  arr[i] = rand() % 75 + 1;
  for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
     ...
  }
} while (k != 1);
```

Note it is also useless to check looking at all the array including the entries not set by a random value, so can be :

```
do
{
  k = 0;
  arr[i] = rand() % 75 + 1;
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {
    if (arr[i] == arr[j])
    {
      k++;
    }
  }
} while (k != 0);
```

because now *j* cannot values *i* the test is `(k != 0)` rather than `(k != 1)`

or better because when an identical value is found there is no reason to continue

```
do
{
  arr[i] = rand() % 75 + 1;
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {
    if (arr[i] == arr[j])
      break;
  }
} while (j != i);
```

---

To see well the values also add a space between them and add a final newline:

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
putchar('\n');
```

AFter these changes, compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall r.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
74 60 16 65 54 19 55 45 41 24 39 59 66 36 27 22 68 49 29 14 28 5 71 56 72 

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
16 34 62 29 74 41 3 43 69 17 61 22 28 59 7 65 5 46 60 20 66 14 49 54 45 

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

**edit**

The implementation is simple but it can take time to find a not yet used value in that way, and the more the range of allowed values is closer to the number of values to return the higher the needed time is. So that solution is good when there are few values to return compared to the range of allowed values.

It is the reverse concerning the interesting proposal of Weather Vane, the number of call to *rand* is only equals to number of values to return, but the more the range of allowed values is large the more the array *bag* is large up to may be overflow the memory size.

Probably for 25 values from 1 to 75 the solution of Weather Vane is better ... even my proposal seems to need just 0.001 sec on my raspberry pi so almost nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
int *fillint(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    int added = 0;
    int pos = 0
    while(pos != size)
    {
        int rv;
        do
        {
            added = 1;
            rv = rand();

            for(size_t index = 0; index < pos; index++)
            {
                if(arr[index] == rv)
                {
                    added = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while(!added)
        arr[pos++] = rv;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another slight variation on Weather Vane's *bag* approach, is rather than preparing a bag of all available numbers, simply declare an array with the max number of elements equal to the range of numbers accepted initialized to all zero (e.g. `int arr[75] = {0};` in this case). There is no need to populate the array, you will simply increment the element by 1 each time that number is used in filling your array.

To ensure you use only unique number you check whether the corresponding element of the array is zero, if it is, use that number and increment the element. If it is non-zero, you know that number has been used - generate another and try again.

For example with the number of integers for the array being `25` and the maximum value of any one integer being `75`, you could do;:

```
#define NINT 25
#define MAXI 75
...
    int arr[NINT],
        seen[MAXI] = {0};
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < NINT; i++) {    /* for each needed element */
        int tmp = rand() % MAXI + 1;    /* generate a random in range */
        while (seen[tmp-1])             /* has been seen/used yet? */
            tmp = rand() % MAXI + 1;    /* if so, generate another */
        seen[tmp-1]++;                  /* incement element */
        arr[i] = tmp;                   /* assign unique value to arr */
    }
```

(**note:** the `seen` indexes are mapped as `tmp-1` to map to valid indexes `0-74` while the numbers generated for `tmp` will be `1-75` using `rand() % MAXI + 1`. You can accommodate any range needed by this type of mapping. Using a range of numbers from `1000001 - 1000075` would still only require a 75-element `seen` array.)

To output the numbers used in order, you simply need to output the index corresponding to each of the non-zero elements of the `seen` array (`+1` to map back into the `1-75` values range), e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXI; i++)
        if (seen[i])
            printf (" %d", i + 1);
    putchar ('\n');
```

Putting it altogether in a short example you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NINT 25
#define MAXI 75

int main (void) {

    int arr[NINT],
        seen[MAXI] = {0};
    srand (time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < NINT; i++) {    /* for each needed element */
        int tmp = rand() % MAXI + 1;    /* generate a random in range */
        while (seen[tmp-1])             /* has been seen/used yet? */
            tmp = rand() % MAXI + 1;    /* if so, generate another */
        seen[tmp-1]++;                  /* incement element */
        arr[i] = tmp;                   /* assign unique value to arr */
    }

    puts ("array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < NINT; i++) {
        if (i && i % 5 == 0)
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %2d", arr[i]);
    }

    puts ("\n\nused:");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXI; i++)
        if (seen[i])
            printf (" %d", i + 1);
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

(**note:** obviously the size of the seen array will be limited to the available stack size, so if your range of needed numbers exceeds the memory available for `seen` declared with *automatic storage type*, you will need to make `seen` an array with *allocated storage type*).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/randarr25-75
array:
  1 18 70 26 75
 29 31 58 22  9
  5 13  3 25 35
 40 48 44 57 56
 60 50 71 67 43

used:
 1 3 5 9 13 18 22 25 26 29 31 35 40 43 44 48 50 56 57 58 60 67 70 71 75
```

Whether you use a bag, or an array to track the numbers seen, the results are the same. No one better than the other. Add them both to your C-toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

In the inner for loop, the one for j, iterate until j < i, to check if the value generated at step i has been already generated at a earlier step.

Also, initialize the value of k to be zero every time you check for previous occurrences, this makes the code more easy to read.

If one occurrence was found, just break, it make the algorithm to run faster, even if it only make a difference for big values.

Something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    k = 1;
    while (k != 0)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 75 + 1;
        k = 0; 

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                k++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `k = 0; while (k != 0) {...}` ? ^^ (I am not the down voter)

Comment: @bruno Yes, you're right, I've made a logical mistake. Edited it. Thanks!